# Probability question with infinite trial

Tags: probability, statistics

You and a group of infinitely many friends have $1$ dollar in a casino.

Slot machines are $1$ to play, and with three possible outcomes:

Win 2 dollars, $P(Win) = 1/5$, 
$P(Lose) = 1/5$, 
or Null (you get your $1$ dollar back, P(Null) = 3/5).

At the start, you use the $1$ dollar to play. 
On each play, if you win, you pass your extra dollar to one of your friends 
and you both proceed to play on different machines;

if they win, they pass their extra dollar to another friend, who also starts playing, and so on.

If a person loses, they stop playing and leave the casino;

if a person gets a Null, they re-use the dollar and continue to play.

Successive plays are independent, and the casino has infinitely many slot machines.

If you and your friends keep playing indefinitely, what’s the probability you all go broke? Hint: P(Broke|$2$ dollars) = (P(Broke|$1))^2$]

I understand the hint because you need to lose a dollar twice but I don't know where to go from there

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.  Specifically, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960 and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_k$ be the probability of going broke if $k$ people are playing.  We need to compute $p_1$.  We have$$p_1=\frac15+\frac35p_1+\frac15p_2$$

Can you finish it?